# Cannot Assign Value of tyoe 'CDAccount.Type'to type 'CDAccount' SwiftUI

Tags: core-data, swiftui, init

I have a core data model account CDAccount and trying to send this account data to AccountDetail view. so that I can get selectedStatusIndex value and reach its value from the previous view.

I am trying to set its value inside the init block but whatever I try I get an error for an account.

```
 struct AccountDetail: View {
    @Binding var account : CDAccount!
    @State var selectedStatusIndex: Int
    @State var status : [String]
    init(account: CDAccount) {
        self.account = CDAccount?
        self.selectedStatusIndex = Int(account.statusIndex)
        self.status = Constants.Status.status
    }
    var body: some View {
        Picker(selection: $selectedStatusIndex, label: Text("Status")) {
            ForEach(0..<status.count) {
//                Text(status[Int(account.statusIndex)])
                Text("\(self.status[$0])")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is account a Binding? You don’t seem to modify it. Without the binding annotation, it would just be self.account = account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the first two lines of your init

```
init(account: Binding<CDAccount>) {
     self._account = account
```

Also, you don’t need the exclamation

```
 @Binding var account : CDAccount
```

You should also get rid of `@State var selectedStatusIndex` unless you intend for the changes to not affect the `account` and for the changes to be reset when SwiftUI decides to reload the `View`.

The Apple way so you can avoid the reload is like this for the second one.

```
@State var status : [String] = Constants.Status.status
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare `account` as a variable of type `CDAccount`:

```
@Binding var account : CDAccount!
```

Then in this line

```
self.account = CDAccount?
```

...you assign the `CDAccount` type to that variable. The variable is an instance of `CDAccount`. `CDAccount` on its own is the class that represents all instances of the type.

It's hard to tell what you're trying to do here, but you can't assign a class to something that wants an instance of that class. You need to create and instance, or provide one from somewhere else in your app.

Comment: If I don’t add self.account = CDAccount? init gives error as you did not declare all the instances inside init. I am just trying to get rid of this problem. Having @Binding var account : CDAccount! is enough for me to be able to reach its data. But Xcode wants more inside init block

Comment: If you don't add that, the code is also incorrect, but for a different reason. Changing it to be the way it is now doesn't fix the problem, it replaces one problem with a new one.